# SVN commit behavior / failure criateria

Tags: java, svn, jakarta-ee, subclipse

So I'm making some changes/fixes to someone's subclipse mod and had a few questions.

First, I noticed that an svn commit fails when trying to commit a single file that is identical to the existing one in the repository. (And returns -1 for the revision #) Makes sense.
Does this happen if you commit multiple files, only some of which have no changes?

Is the best way around this to just do a diff (on every file?) before attempting to commit?

If anyone knows, that'd be great. Or if you can point me in the right direction? (My google-fu failed me)

Comment: Something sounds wrong. Like the file in WC is in the repo *already*, but the WC doesn't know it? Oh, the SVN nightmares are returning. But should be okay if "updated" first. I stopped using SVN.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the file is identical, SVN will not commit it.  If you provide a list of files, the ones that are identical will just be skipped.  I assume you are working with the SVN API and not Subclipse GUI or command line client as you do not see a -1 in either of those.

Answer (score 1):

If you are 100% sure the file is 'identical', then the quickest solution would be to do a 'revert' on the troublesome file (by right-clicking on the file then selecting 'Team' then 'Revert'). Subversion does 'atomic' commits, ( [What is the value of atomic commits in Subversion?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1602642/what-is-the-value-of-atomic-commits-in-subversion) ) , which basically means if one commit fails in a batch commit, then they all fail.