# svn client timing out and corrupting WC state

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

When I commit large changes - hundreds of megabytes - the client timesout even though the check-in does go through.

When I right-click on WC and show log, TSVN shows that WC revision does NOT get updated even though the check-in actually occurred.

I've tried using `TortoiseSVN 1.9.5, Build 27581 - 64 Bit` and command line `svn version 1.9.5 (r1770682)`.

**QUESTION**

Is there a way to increase the timeout of the client?

Comment: Show how you're doing the commits in the first place. Are you telling Subversion to commit 10 files, and only 5 are being committed? Or are you assuming that 10 files will be committed but only 5 are eligible for it?

Comment: @alroc in TSVN, i right click on folder and commit which shows dozens of files able to be committed. I press ok and sometimes it says commit failed but the repo log says a commit did occur but only for some files.

Comment: If you get "failed" as a response, then nothing should be changed in the repository. Are you certain that all of the files you *think* are being committed really are attempted? Do you have unversioned files showing that you're assuming will be committed, but you haven't checked the box to do so?

Comment: Please, describe the behavior in detail. [Commits & revisions in SVN **are atomic**](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.basic.in-action.html#svn.basic.in-action.revs) by design. Therefore, its unclear why you "get partial commits".

Comment: @bahrep what additional details can I provide?

Comment: @alroc I know how to use TSVN. That's not the problem

Comment: Show us an example of what you call "non-atomic" commit.

Comment: @bahrep I commit 10 files but 5 files of the 10 get committed.

Comment: SVN commits *should* be atomic, but the storage format is not particularly rock solid. I'd give [snvadmin verify](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.ref.svnadmin.c.verify.html) and [svnadmin recover](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.ref.svnadmin.c.recover.html) a try.

Comment: @alroc I figured out my real problem, question updated

Comment: @bahrep I figured out my real problem, question updated

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález I figured out my real problem, question updated

Comment: I presume it times out because it stalls. Increasing the wait time may not be the solution. Does [anything in this thread](http://grokbase.com/t/subversion/users/14ae68s0dt/svn-1-8-timeout-fix) apply to you?

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález thanks I'll try it.

Comment: Do you use VisualSVN Server with multisite VDFS repositories?

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález your link fixed it. Per my IT, client was timing out exactly 10mins after the data transfer was complete and this is the default timeout.
I set `http-timeout = 3600` and now it works! Set this as your answer so I can select it and close this question.

Comment: @Adrian I've just composed an answer. However, I'm not 100% sure about how it works for you. Does the server really need more than 10 minutes to process the submission after all data is transmitted?

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález It's because of our network configuration. Short answer is yes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are using HTTP to connect to the server (as it appears to be the case) you can increase (or disable) the time out with the `http-timeout` directive, as explained at [Runtime Configuration Area](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.advanced.confarea.html):

> **http-timeout**
>
> This specifies the amount of time, in seconds, to wait for a server response. If you experience problems with a slow network
>   connection causing Subversion operations to time out, you should
>   increase the value of this option. In Subversion 1.8 (or older
>   versions employing the Serf-based HTTP provider), use the value 0 to
>   disable the timeout altogether.

Just make sure you aren't merely masking a problem (it's strange that commit completes successfully but server response doesn't make through).

Comment: Yep this was the issue.

Comment: Quirkily publishing a crucial documentation reference here, for others (and me) experiencing this issue on git-svn:
on git-svn, the exact timeout message string occurring in case of an unfit (insufficient) subversion http-timeout setting is:
`Connection timed out: Connection timed out at /usr/share/perl5/Git/SVN/Ra.pm line 312.`